# Riesz representation theorem: an application

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, riesz-representation-theorem

Let $L_n\colon C_c(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with
$$ L_nf = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n}  e^{k/n} f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right).  $$
Prove that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}L_nf=:Lf$ exists and then apply the Riesz representation theorem to $L$.

Until now I proved the existence of the limit.

> Do you have any idea of how to continue the exercise?

Comment: You have an $n$ in the index $L_n$, but still sum over $n$ in the right hand side. Is that intended? Furthermore, the exercise is not formulated very precisely. Do you want to know what the resulting measure is?

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes, I would like to find the measure because I should use it next. Whould it be helpful if we calculate $lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}L_nf$ so that we can use the fact that $Lf=\int f\mathrm{d}\mu?$

Comment: Yes, but as I said, the problem is that $L_n f$ (which should depend on $n$) is defined as $\sum_{\color{red} n = 1}^\infty (\text{expression depending on }n)$. Hence, $L_n$ does not actually depend on $n$. So: What is the correct defintion of $L_n$?

Comment: Maybe $L_nf=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n} e^{k/n}f(\frac{k}{n})$ for $n=1,2,...$

Comment: Yes, that is what I thought. In this case, you should be able to show that $L_n f \to \int g(x) \cdot f(x) \, dx$ for some (suitable, fixed) function $g$ and all $f \in C_c$. To see this, interpret $L_nf$ as the Riemann sum of $\int g\cdot f\, dx$ for a suitable $g$.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score -1):

Using the Riemann sum, one readly observes that 
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}L_nf = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n}  e^{k/n} f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right) =\int_0^1e^xf(x)dx $$
for each $f\in C_c(\Bbb R). $ whence set $$Lf= \int_0^1e^xf(x)dx $$

Since $x\mapsto e^x$ is in $L^2(0,1)$ there is not problem if we extend $L$ by taking $f\in L^2(0,1)$

that is 
$$Lf= \int_0^1e^xf(x)dx=\langle f,e^x\rangle_{L^2} ~~~~~ f\in L^2(0,1).$$
this is directly the Riesz representation theorem.